# Firestore transaction update multiple collections in a single transaction

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

How can i update multiple collections in firestore by using a single transaction i searched but i didn't get any answers. Is it possible to update multiple collections in a single transaction?

I want to **update** **branch.name** at-once in classroom & students collection
[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't get it, what is the relationship between classroom and students, what is branch and if it have Id, why you don't move it out and make it to a new collection?

Comment: A transaction doesn't allow you to modify all of the documents in a collection.  You have to identify each document you want to change, and work with them each individually within the transaction handler.  You are able to modify documents among multiple collections this way.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As explained in the documentation for the Node.js Client Library [`update()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.firestore.Transaction.html#update) method, it returns a [`Transaction`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.firestore.Transaction.html)  which is "**used for chaining method calls**." (Note that [`update()`](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/Transaction.html#update) method of the Admin SDK behaves exactly the same way).

So, for example, if within the transaction you want to get a value from a classroom doc, increase it and use it to update two documents from two different collections (`classrooms` and `students`), you would do as follows:

```
const db = firebase.firestore();  //or admin.firestore() in a Cloud Function
const docRef1 = db.collection('classrooms').doc('classroomDocId');
const docRef2 = db.collection('students').doc('studentDocId');


let transaction = db.runTransaction(t => {
  let newNumericValue;
  return t.get(docRef1 )
    .then(doc => {
      newNumericValue = doc.data().numericValue + 1;  //You calculate the new value
      return t.update(docRef1 , {numericValue : newNumericValue});
    }).then(t => {
      return t.update(docRef2 , {numericValue : newNumericValue});
    });
}).then(result => {
  console.log('Transaction success!' + result);
}).catch(err => {
  console.log('Transaction failure:', err);
});
```

---

Note that if you need to do several reads before your multiple updates, "when using transactions, **read operations must come before write operations**."

---

On the other hand, **IF YOU JUST WANT TO UPDATE** multiple documents **WITHOUT READING** one or more values (you say in your question that you "want to update branch.name at-once in classroom & students collection "), you don't need to use a transaction. Just use a [batched write](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#batched-writes), as follows:

```
let batch = db.batch();

let cRef = db.collection('classrooms').doc('classroomDocId');
batch.set(cRef, {branch.name: 'newName'});

let sRef = db.collection('students').doc('studentDocId');
batch.update(sRef, {branch.name: 'newName'});

return batch.commit().then(function () {
  // ...
});
```

---

**UPDATE Following your comments**

In your Cloud Function, you can very well chain different Firestore queries (with `where()`) and in each `then()` populate the batch and then in the last `then()` commit the batch. See below for an example (just adapt with the correct queries):

```
 let batch = admin.firestore().batch();

 return admin.firestore().collection('students').where('branch.id', '==', documentId).get()
 .then((querySnapshot) => {
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => { 
        batch.update(doc.ref, {branch: {id: documentId, name: after.name}}); 
    });
    return admin.firestore().collection('student_public').where('branch.id', '==', documentId).get();
 })
 .then((querySnapshot) => {
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => { 
        batch.update(doc.ref, {branch: {id: documentId, name: after.name}}); 
    });
    return batch.commit() 
 })
 .catch(err => { console.log('error===>', err); });
```

Comment: thanks for the help, this is my batch update code 

`let batch = admin.firestore().batch();

        admin.firestore().collection('students').where('branch.id', '==', documentId).get()
            .then((querySnapshot) => {
                querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
                    batch.update(doc.ref, {branch: {id: documentId, name: after.name}});
                });
                return batch.commit();
            }).catch(err => {
            console.log('error===>', err);
        }); `

Comment: but my problem is how can i apply the same logic to many documents with **where clause**
ex:  `let student_public = admin.firestore().collection('student_public').where('branch.id', '==', documentId);`

`let classrooms = admin.firestore().collection('classrooms').where('branch.id', '==', documentId);`

Comment: I understand your code is Cloud Function code. You should take care to return the promise returned by `get()` (See the 3 videos about "JavaScript Promises" from the Firebase video series: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/video-series/ which explain this key point).

Comment: You can very well chain different Firestore queries (with where) and in each then() populate the batch and then in the last then commit the batch.  promises