# How to update data in multiple location (e.g. top level collection, subcollection)?

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore

Here is my DB:

[image]

[image]

[image]

I want to update the fullName of a member in multiple locations all at once. The fullName of a member is inside AnnualDue, MemberFee, and Faculty.

Comment: Have you tried [Transactions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions) and barched writes? Can you have a look at this [StackOverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57653880/18265570)?

Comment: I think it cannot be achieved using transactions and batched writes because the IDs are unknown

Comment: Does this [StackOverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61136301/18265570) helps you?

Comment: @RoopaM not really. I did not find any solution in that link. In fact, I did not find a solution even in Firestore documentation. I guess I have to run multiple queries from different collections at once and then update at once but I think its a bad practice and can cost me a lot.

Comment: How about considering maps as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46945340/18265570)?